# Cross FormView fields update

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

I have an ASP.NET page (`C#` codebehind) with two `FormView` both of these are bound to the same underlying `SQL` table but `SQLDataSource` objects feeding the forms are different because I needed two different `UpdateCommand`. 
The problem arise when I 'update' the second form trough it's `SQLDataSource`, the fields in such form are updated while those of the first are not. I tried to force the `SQLDataSource` object bound to the first form to update it's data with `Select()` method but without luck.
Is it possibile to 'force' the first form to update it's own fields after I update the second one?

ASP code:

```
<asp:FormView
    ID="_fvData1"
    runat="server"
    DataKeyNames="id"
    DataSourceID="_sdsData1"
    DefaultMode="Edit" 
    Width="100%">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox 
            ClientIDMode="Static" 
            CausesValidation="true"
            ID="_txtData1" 
            runat="server" 
            Text='<%#Eval("data1","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%>' />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>

<asp:FormView
    ID="_fvData2"
    runat="server"
    DataKeyNames="id"
    DataSourceID="_sdsData2"
    DefaultMode="Edit" 
    Width="100%">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox 
            ClientIDMode="Static" 
            CausesValidation="true"
            ID="_txtData1" 
            runat="server" 
            Text='<%#Eval("data1","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%>' />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>

<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="_sdsData1" 
    runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sos_db %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sos_db.ProviderName %>"
    SelectCommand=" SELECT
                         *                                            
                    FROM
                         table_a
                    WHERE
                         id=@id;"
     UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"
     UpdateCommand="update_table_a_procedure_a">
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="id" Type="Int32" QueryStringField="id" />
     </SelectParameters>
     <UpdateParameters>
         <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="id" Type="Int32" QueryStringField="id" />
     </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="_sdsData2" 
    runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sos_db %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sos_db.ProviderName %>"
    OnUpdated="_sdsData2_Updated"
    SelectCommand=" SELECT
                         *                                            
                    FROM
                         table_a
                    WHERE
                         id=@id;"
     UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"
     UpdateCommand="update_table_a_procedure_b">
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="id" Type="Int32" QueryStringField="id" />
     </SelectParameters>
     <UpdateParameters>
         <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="id" Type="Int32" QueryStringField="id" />
     </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void _sdsData2_Updated(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    _sdsData1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Can add an image of what you explained here? Its a bit confusing reading and assuming the scenario.

Comment: of course I can. I'm going to insert the exact code I'm using.